# DSolve Second Order Differential Equation with One Boundary Condition

Tags: differential-equations

So I set up my singular perturbation problem after change of variables for equation and boundary condition. But when using DSolve  for the analytical solution, there's always a 1/2 in front of it. Can someone take a look at my set up and tell me what went wrong? Thanks!

```
singOrd1 = 2 Derivative[1][Y0][X] + (Y0^\[Prime]\[Prime])[X] == 0
bc1YOrd1 = Y0[0] == 0
solSing1 = Y0[X] /. DSolve[{singOrd1, bc1YOrd1}, Y0[X], X][[1]]
```

[image]

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: What's wrong with `C[1]/2` as a coefficient?

Comment: Where is the 1/2 come from?

Comment: It's a linear homogeneous system with a homogeneous BC: If $y$ is a solution, then so is $\alpha y$ for any scalar $\alpha$. Someone else's solution may have a different constant multiple than yours, but they're both still correct. One might be able to guess how *Mathematica* produced a solution with a factor of $1/2$, but I'm not sure what it matters. It just reflects different, valid choices along each solution path.

Comment: You can get rid of the $1/2$ by `solSing1 /. C[1] -> 2 C[1]`, if desired. It's a valid transformation, since `C[1]` is an arbitrary scalar constant.

Answer (score 4):

> Where is the 1/2 come from?

This is because it is second order ode, and you have one B.C condition.

The general solution generates two constant of integrations.

So it is arbitrary which one of these two is solved for from the one condition given. `DSolve` choose to solve for `C[1]`. If you solve for `C[2]` instead, the `1/2` goes away.

```
ClearAll[y, x];
ode = 2 y'[x] + y''[x] == 0
bc = y[0] == 0
sol = y[x] /. First@DSolve[ode, y[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now apply the BC conditon on the solution

```
eq = 0 == sol /. x -> 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compare the particular solution now when choosing to solve for either constant. Choosing to solve for `C[1]` gives

```
sol /. Solve[eq, C[1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And Choosing to solve for `C[2]` gives

```
sol /. Solve[eq, C[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So both are valid solutions. But it depends on the choice used to solve for the constant of integration. `DSolve` choose to solve for `C[1]`. And since the constant that remains is arbitrary, it can be named anything else. say $C$. so you end up with any one of these two particular solutions

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Both are valid and equivalent solutions since $C$ is constant, it does not matter if one writes `C` or `C/2` or `C/10` or `C/100`. After using the second B.C., the same answer will result.